# Can as device that runs of USB be powered from a charger?

Tags: usb, power-supply, power, charger

I have a Dreamgear PS3 Elite Gaming Headset that needs to be plugged into a USB port to power it, it cannot be used as just a "normal" set of headphones though it has a standard 3.5" plug as well (don't ask me why, it just can't).

My question is "Can I power it by using a 5v 1A Apple iPhone charger instead of a USB port."
The main reason is to do school work on an iPad, which I am pretty sure will not power it.
T.I.A
darrennie

Comment: If you already have the headset and the charge why don't you just try it?

Comment: Or alternatively you could get a iPad OTG adapter so you can plug the headphones into it and power it from the iPad.

Comment: @Griffin, as they are not my headphones I want to make sure be for I toast them or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any technical specs (i.e. voltage/amp's) on how much that headset uses, but if it is USB compliant (which if it's drawing power from the USB port, it is), then the answer is YES. Any device that can draw from a 5V/1A powered USB line can use the Apple iPhone charger (or any 5V/1A USB charger for that matter).

Of course don't take my word for it as I don't have the technical specs and there might be some other filters in the headset I'm unaware of that, if plugged in to an invalid power source, could blow (though chances or more likely that it will work, just issuing a disclaimer if the headset no longer functions after plugging it in).

Comment: Problem: What if it receives information through USB on top of just power?

Comment: USB is split into different 'lines' (if you will) that give the device(s) both its power and ability to communicate. An electrical engineer wouldn't (shouldn't) cross the USB data lines with the USB power lines on the device. Technically speaking, as long as the device and adapter conform to the USB spec then only the power draw should occur (even if the device attempts communication, nothing is plugged in but the power side, so nothing will happen) ... hence the disclaimer though since I do not have the tech specs of the headset :)